# Is it possible to get my current location at the desktop by using geolocation

Tags: geolocation

As the question tells, I hope to know if it's enable to get my current position at the desktop rather than mobile devices such as phone.

Comment: You set custom location in xcode

Answer (score -1):

In Windows 10 it's possible, and maybe for Windows 8.1 and MacOS do

Comment: this should be posted in comment